# Как при клике на ссылку взять форму из файла?

Tags: jquery, ajax

На странице есть ссылка:

```
<div id="message">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="AddForm();">получить форму</a>
</div>
```

Есть страница `form.php` где находится форма:

```
<form id="" action="" method="">
<textarea></textarea>
</form>
```

Но простенький казалось бы скрипт почему-то не работает:

```
function AddForm(){
    $.ajax({url:"/form.php",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(msg) {
        $("#message").html(msg);
    }
    });
};
```

Все пути к скриптам правильные. Консоль ошибок не выдает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

чистый JS:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:formRequest.doRequest()">

var formRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
formRequest.doRequest = function () {
    this.open("GET", "/form.php", true);
    this.send(null);
}
formRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
}
```

Сей код точно должен отработать, хотя в вашем я тоже не вижу ошибки...
Попробуйте мой вариант если не работает пишите...
PS:если уже грузите jquery, то выборку делайте не

```
document.getElementById("message")
```

a

```
$("#message")
```

ну и для порядочности не `innerHTML` а `html()`

И посмотрите, у вас form.php нормально отрабатывает?

И самое главное - не проще ли просто всунуть форму на страницу, сделать ее `display:none` и при клике просто менять display?

Comment: form.php нормально отрабатывает. а скрипт даже ваш не заработал.

Comment: Исправил свой скрипт как вы написали. И добился ошибки :)
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

О чем она говорит?

Comment: сайт в сети или на локалке? если в сети ссылку...

Comment: на локалке

Comment: Такое возникает если например в теле условия написать не `if(someVar==someValue)` а `if(someVar=someValue)`...
т.е. скорее всего пропустили гдето знак =, <, > или чето в этому духе...

Comment: Но в моей функции даже условия нет, я обновил функцию, которая сейчас используется.

Comment: Да. Вы были правы. В строке $("#message").html() == msg; у меня было одно равно. Я исправил, но скрипт не пожелал работать. И даже ошибку не выдает.

Comment: Вместо
    
    `$("#message").html() == msg`

пишем

    `$("#message").html(msg);`

Закрываем вопрос, учим jquery :)

Answer (score 0):

чтобы form.php что то выводил/возвращал надо сделать там вывод на экран. Проще говоря в функцию echo или print надо запихнуть код вашей формы. тогда будет результат.

```
  <?php
       $form='form html code...';
       echo $form;
       exit;
    ?>
```